# Why do you have to stop Magento 1 cron jobs during migration to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, cron

I am preparing for migration from **Magento ver. 1.9** to **Magento ver. 2.2**.

I am trying to fully understand the process and wondering what are the reasons that you have to stop the cron jobs?

All the tutorials say to stop the cron jobs, however, I can't find any information why you have to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to stop crons before proceeding for migration because it can cause issue in our database. we know that cron are used to do particular task on their scheduled time and some crons are used to transfer data from one database table to another table so if we are migrating and cron are still running then it can change data in tables which can cause damage or data missing problems during migration that is why its recommend to stop all crons while migrating.
you can go through the Magento doc here: [Creating a migration plan](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-plan.html)

Answer (score 1):

Cron jobs such as reindexing can and do cause locks in your database. These will prevent the migration from doing its job. Disabling the cron jobs will prevent this from happening.